# Node post request is getting unauthorized server status but client fetch api is not

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

When making the following fetch request on my front-end I'm getting my desired `type` and `id` values.

```
export const getUserProfile = () => {
  return (
    fetch(
      "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me", {
      headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + user_id}
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data.type)
      console.log(data.id)
    })
  )
}
```

Knowing you can't use fetch api in Node I used the `npm install request` package to get the data on my node server.

```
request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
  var access_token = body.access_token
  let postInfo = {
    url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
    headers: {
      "Authoriztion": "Bearer " + access_token
    },
    json: true
  }
  request.post(postInfo, function(error, response, body) {
    const route = body.type
    const current_user_id = body.id
    console.log(body)
    let uri = process.env.FRONTEND_URI || `http://localhost:3000/${route}/${current_user_id}`
    res.redirect(uri + '?access_token=' + access_token)
  })
})
```

The purpose of doing this is so when the `res.redirect` gets called it sends the client to the user's home page. However when the client gets redirected the url is `http://localhost:3000/undefined/undefined?accesss_token={some token}`
when looking why the values are undefined I `console.log(body)` and I get

```
{
  error: { 
    status: 401,
    message: 'No token provided'
  }
}
```

but I can see when logging the response that the token is included

`_header: 'POST /v1/me HTTP/1.1\r\nAuthoriztion: Bearer {some token}=\r\nhost: api.spotify.com\r\naccept: application/json\r\ncontent-length: 0\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n'`

I can see why my values are undefined but why am I getting an unauthorized status in node but not on the client using fetch api? Also I noticed that the url `access_token` doesn't match the server logged token.

Here are the docs I'm using:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/users-profile/get-current-users-profile/

Github file: https://github.com/ryansaam/litphum-server/blob/master/server.js

Comment: this is just a guess, but instead of `(new Buffer(access_token).toString('base64'))` just try `access_token` - i.e. don't base64 it

Comment: @Robbie When doing this I did notice that the server was logging the same `access_token` as the client url. I'm still getting unauthorized 401 though.

Comment: sounds like the base64 isn't required then - I'm not sure why its still 401 - did you make sure there is still a space char between `Bearer ` and the access_token? is the message still `No token provided`? or has it changed?

Comment: @Robbie Yes there is a space char. I'm going to to update my question with the github page that shows the whole file if you would like to take a look and see if there could be another problem.

Comment: looks like a spelling mistake. You've spelt `Authorization` incorrectly as `Authoriztion` - i've commented on the commit in github - here in your SO post, you have spelt it correctly.

Comment: @Robbie Yeah I noticed that. Thanks for pointing that out. Now I'm noticing that the `response` nor the `body` are returning the user data so I'm going to take a look at that. But that might be the correct answer because I'm no longer getting a 401.

Comment: sounds like the auth is fixed then - i can't see an obvious reason the user data is missing - check what status code your getting - or if the error has anything, good luck

Comment: are you sure that you are using CORS policy correctly?

Comment: @NuriddinKudratov I solved all my issues first by fixing my typo in `headers` and then instead of using `request` I used `node-fetch` for a more familiar api. I'm still new at writing node servers so this is the best solution I could come up with. Also I don't know much about CORS but I'm not getting anymore errors so I think I'm okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `node-fetch` in your server code, you have a similar API as `fetch`.